# How to bevel a screwed tunnel into a seamless backdrop?

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

I want to merge and bevel the tunnel's spiraled stripes into a seamless backdrop. Thus the backdrop is of made of the similar 5 stripes as the screw, though not screwed anymore.

[image: picture]

How can I achieve that?

The smaller trumpet(#1) serves as other depiction of my imagination to merge and bevel the spiral and seamless backdrop.

[image: picture]
[image]

Comment: It is a first time I see someone starts whole cable from single vertex :) Awesome. Just a big disadvantage is you have to use very dense topo to get desired shape. I followed your system, but seems to me lighter to create base segment from faces with better top and than use modifiers ... or to add one Subdivision after first Screw...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*From your question I'm not sure about final desired shape, but you can try Lattice modifier or Surface Deform modifier*

### Step 01

- First you would need to straight ends of cable - just change your *Screw.001* modifier > Screw > 0 m

[image]

### Step 02 - version Lattice

- Now you can add **Lattice** object under *Lattice Properties* change *Resolution* to 3. Position it at the end of cable. Add Lattice Modifier to cable, choose object Lattice. Select Lattice switch to edit mode and scale bottom part.

[image]

- If you don't mind make cable circular increase *Screw.001 >* **Steps Viewport/Render** to **20**. Also there is not a necessary to have first *Screw* modifier *Steps* 64 ... 24 seems to work as well.

[image]

### Step 02 - version Surface Deform

if you want the cable from flat segments (as in your example) try it with **Surface Deform** modifier (but there is probably many other ways)

- add *Subdivision* modifier to get more segments on straight end edge
- add *Cylinder*, in edit mode add two *Edge Loops*, add *Subdivision* modifier too
- add *Surface Deform* modifier, select *Cylinder* as object, than *BIND*
- now if use change *Cylinder* shape (like scale bottom edge loops it will shape Cable end)

[image]

- anyway modifiers use in order - Displace, Array, Screw, Screw.001, Latice or Surface Deform, Curve, Solidify, Bevel

[image]

[image]

### Step 03

To let "trumpet" shrink on "backdrop" curved part ... try your luck with **Vertex Weight Proximity** modifier with backdrop object as *Target*, it will generate a vertex *Group* with weight that we can use for **ShrinkWrap** modifier .